# Prove that if $G$ is connected graph of order $n$ and size $m$ that has $K_k$ as a minor, then $m \geq n+ \binom{k}{2}-k$

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that if $G$ is connected graph of order $n$ and size $m$ that has $K_k$ as a minor, then $m \geq n+ \binom{k}{2}-k$

I think I need a proof by induction, but before that I need to make sure that I get every info from the question.

Here is what I understand so far, let $H=K_k$ be a minor of $G$, then $H$ can be obtain by contracting edges of $G$. Since $m(H) =\binom {k}{2}$ it's easy to understand that $m(G) > \binom {k}{2}$ but how do I know how many  edges are contracted?

I really want to understand this before the second midterm, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Say $G$ is a linear graph of order $n=101$, size $m=100$. Delete an edge and the resulting isolated vertex from one of the ends of the graph and let this new graph be $K$. now $K$ has order $k=100$, and $\binom{k}{2}=4950$. Now im quite sure that $100\ge101+4950-100$ is a false statement. Are you sure this was the question?

Comment: yes, I copied it word by word from the book, and I'm not understand the question very clearly either.

Comment: Do you understand my counterexample? Or I got the question wrong?(this happens...)

Comment: yes, although it's kinda hard to have a picture in my head because the number of vertices and edges is so big. Are you sure you have a $K_{100}$ as minor?, because the graph has size $100$, how can it has minor with $4950$ edges?

Comment: It doesn't have $4950$ edges, but $\binom{100}{2}=4950$. $K$ would have $99$ edges(and $100$ vertices) since we deleted one edge and one vertex from $G$, but the number of edges of $K$ is not relevant.

Comment: the question says $G$ has $K_k$ as minor, so if $k=100$, then we have $K_{100}$ as minor right? the size of $K_{100}=\binom {100}{2}=4950$

Comment: You are assuming thet a minor is a complete graph, i think. There is no need for that, [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor) .

Comment: I thought that is what the question said, the question said the minor is $K_k$ meaning the minor is a complete graph of order $k$, is it not?

Comment: So I understood the question wrong! I thought that $K_k$ just meant *graph K of order k*. If I come up with a proof I will post it.

Comment: @chubakueno Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using induction sounds like a great idea.  I would induct on the number of edge contractions needed to achieve $K_k$.  If no contractions are needed, then $G = K_k$ and the result is obvious.  If $G$ needs some number of edge contractions, then perform one of these contractions to achieve a graph $G'$ with order $n'$ and size $m'$.  By induction, $G'$ would satisfy the inequality $m' \geq n' + {k \choose 2} - k$.  Since we lose one vertex and at least one edge going from $G$ to $G'$, we have $n - 1= n'$ and $m - 1\geq m'$.  Hence $m \geq n + {k \choose 2} - k$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but  have a question. You do induction on the number of edges contraction, let's call this number $t$. In the base : you let $t=0$, this is straight forward. In inductive step you assume that this is work when you do $t-1$ edges contracting?

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif:  Yes.  $G'$ is $t-1$ edge contractions from a $K_k$, so by induction we know $G'$ satisfies the inequality.